# if/then with VBScript in ArcGIS Field Calculator giving Error 000539: SyntaxError: invalid syntax?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator, vbscript, error-000539

What is wrong with this VBscript in the field calculator?

ColumnC=

```
if [ColumnB] > 0 then
    [ColumnC] = [ColumnA] / [ColumnB]
endif
```

Each time I receive this syntax error message:

> Error 000539: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (expression, line 1) Failed
>   to execute

All 3 columns are the double field type, although they vary in precision and scale. I have tried converting the columns to float type and doing the same expression. I received the same error messages.

For the first line (starting with 'if'), the script is left-justified. For the second line (starting with '[ColumnC]) I included four spaces before the script. In the codeblock on the field calculator the equation does extend into the third line (and is left justified) simply because the actual name I use for !ColumnB! is longer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the returned value in a variable, not reference the column itself.

Expression:

```
result
```

Codeblock:

```
if [ColumnB] > 0 then
    result = [ColumnA] / [ColumnB]
else
    result = 0
end if
```

Here's how the two parts fit together in the field calculator - my data doesn't have the same field names, but you get the idea.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the codeblock? The expression should be just "result" and the codeblock is the rest. VBScript doesn't care about indentation.

Comment: bubbalouie Please add a screen shot of your field calculator to your question, there are a few things that would be explained by that. @phloem, if you do the same that should clear it up.